# Cordova Android - Editing build.gradle

Tags: cordova, build.gradle

I develop an Android Cordova app.

Since I installed a new plugin (cordova-plugin-filepath) I can't compile the app. The reason:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>
> Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

I found that if I comment out from `build.gradle` the line:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"
```

I can compile from Android Studio, install on devices and export apk's.

The problem is that once I run `cordova build android` the `build.gradle` file resets and the line is not commented anymore.

1. Where is the original place I should edit?
2. Is commenting out this line is the right thing to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That file is made from combining original build files with configuration from all the plugins. In `cordova-lugin-filepath` there is `plugin.xml` file, try removing this line and see if it helps:

```
<framework src="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"/>
```

Comment: It didn't help :/ I tried deleting this line in other files, the only thing that helped was to delete it from "project.properties". The problem is it says: "# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!". But it compiles well in Android studio and with cordova build.. hope nothing bad happens.